# What is the probability of getting exactly 3 two's OR three's when a die is rolled 8 times?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, dice

What is the probability of getting exactly $3$ two's OR three's when a die is rolled $8$ times?

I know that $P(E) = |E| / |S|$.

I believe that $|S| = 36$, since there are $36$ different combinations when rolling a die. I am not sure how to get the probability of rolling exactly $3$ two's OR three's when rolling $8$ times.

Comment: I am unclear.  Does $2,2,3,6,6,6,6,6$ count as "exactly $3$ twos or threes"?  What about $2,2,2,3,6,6,6,6$ or $2,2,2,3,3,3,6,6$?

Comment: There are $6^8=1679616$ equally-probable outcomes from $8$ six-sided fair dice rolls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Total number of possible rolls: $6^8 = 1679616$.

I see two possible interpretations of the question. In the following, I answer both of them.

**Interpretation 1**:
*There are exactly 3 twos or exactly 3 threes*

Number of rolls with exactly 3 twos: $\binom{8}{3}\cdot 5^5 = 175000$.
(*Explanation:* $\binom{8}{3}$ is the number of choices of the positions of the twos. The factor $5^5$ comes from the remaining $5$ dice, which have $5$ possibilities (every number except two) each.)

Number of rolls with exactly 3 threes: $\binom{8}{3}\cdot 5^5 = 175000$.

Number of rolls with exactly 3 twos AND exactly 3 threes: $\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{3}\cdot 4^2 = 8960$.

So by the sieve formula, the number of rolls with exactly 3 twos OR exactly 3 threes is $175000 + 175000 - 8960 = 341040$.

Thus, the probability is
$$
\frac{341040}{1679616} \approx 20.3\%.
$$

**Interpretation 2:** *Exactly 3 dice show the digit 2 or 3*

The number of such rolls  is $\binom{8}{3}\cdot 2^3 \cdot 4^5 = 458752$.

So the probability is
$$\frac{458752}{1679616} \approx 27.3\%.$$

Comment: Where does the 5^5 com from?

Comment: @Audrey: I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Probability of exactly $3$ twos is $\binom{8}{3}\left(\frac16\right)^3\left(\frac56\right)^5$.

Probability of exactly $3$ threes is $\binom{8}{3}\left(\frac16\right)^3\left(\frac56\right)^5$.

Probability of exactly $3$ twos and exactly $3$ threes is $\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{3}\left(\frac16\right)^6\left(\frac46\right)^2$

Thus, Inclusion-Exclusion says that the probability of exactly $3$ twos or $3$ threes is
$$
\binom{8}{3}\left(\frac16\right)^3\left(\frac56\right)^5+\binom{8}{3}\left(\frac16\right)^3\left(\frac56\right)^5-\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{3}\left(\frac16\right)^6\left(\frac46\right)^2=\frac{7105}{34992}
$$

Answer (score 0):

total possibilities: $6^8$.

$3$ twos or threes: $4^5\times 2^3\times{8\choose 3}$ (possibilities for remaining $5$ times possibilities for $3$ $2s$/$3s$ times which $3$ consist of $2s$ and $3s$)

${4^5\times 2^3\times{8\choose 3}}\over{6^8}$

interpretation was for $3$ twos or threes e.g., $2,3,3...;3,3,3...;3,2,3...;...$

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking this is a problem of binomial distribution. 
Let $X$ be the random variable denoting the number of $2$'s in $8$ throws of a dice and let $Y$ be the random variable denoting the number of $3$'s in $8$ throws of a dice.
Here, $X,Y \approx Bin(8,\frac{1}{6})$ 
Therefore $P(X=3)= (^8_3)(\frac{1}{6})^3(\frac{5}{6})^5$ 
 and $P(Y=3)= (^8_3)(\frac{1}{6})^3(\frac{5}{6})^5$

Comment: If the die is fair and six-sided then $p=\frac16$. If $X$ is allready defined as random variable then expression $P(X)$ makes no sense.